# How to download file that has a changing file name in R

Tags: r, date, filenames, gunzip

I am trying to download a file into R using this code:

```
temp<-tempfile()
temp2<-tempfile()
download.file("http://WEBSITENAMEHERE_160828.full.rdb.gz",temp)
gunzip(temp, temp2)
```

This code allows the file to be downloaded an unzipped, BUT the "160828" part will change every 7 days to update the data. Meaning, in 7 days, the file will be called "160904" Is there a way for R to automatically change that date every 7 days, or will the user manually have to change it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
tmp <- as.numeric(gsub(x = seq.Date(from = as.Date("16-08-28"),to = as.Date("16-10-04"),by = "week"),pattern = "-",replacement = ""))
#[1] 160828 160904 160911 160918 160925 161002
```

It will take care of the numeric part and use `paste` function to create the full download link.

```
paste0("http://WEBSITENAMEHERE_",tmp,".full.rdb.gz")
#[1] "http://WEBSITENAMEHERE_160828.full.rdb.gz"
#[2] "http://WEBSITENAMEHERE_160904.full.rdb.gz"
#[3] "http://WEBSITENAMEHERE_160911.full.rdb.gz"
#[4] "http://WEBSITENAMEHERE_160918.full.rdb.gz"
#[5] "http://WEBSITENAMEHERE_160925.full.rdb.gz"
#[6] "http://WEBSITENAMEHERE_161002.full.rdb.gz"
```

Comment: how do I put that "as.numeric" part into my URL?

Comment: thank you! one more question, how do I use the output that paste0 uses to retrieve data, like I only want to retrieve data from the most recent update